# Running total with if clause or do while

Tags: sql, window-functions

Consider the following table with 3 columns.

Use this to create a SQL query to list the top products by revenue that make up 25% of the total revenue in 2020.

(i.e. If total revenue is 1000 then list of top products that account for <= 250)

Table `ProductRevenue`:

- Date_DD       ...  date(YYYY-MM-DD)
- Product_Name  ...  varchar(250)
- Revenue       ...   decimal(10,2)

Sample data:

```
Date_DD       Product_Name    Revenue
-------------------------------------
2020-11-30   a                 100 
2020-10-02   b                 100 
2020-07-07   c                 100 
2020-04-04   d                 100 
2020-05-05   f                  50 
2020-06-06   g                 120 
2020-05-30   h                  90 
2020-11-13   k                 120 
2020-01-30   l                 120
```

I used that code but don't know how to use where clause . Anyone can help?

```
SELECT
    product_name, revenue, 
    SUM(revenue) OVER (ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running _total 
FROM
    TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE
```

new code

select product_name, revenue, running_total  from

(SELECT product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total

FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o
where running_total<(select  max(running_total) from

(SELECT product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total

FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o )*0.25
group by product_name, revenue, running_total
order by running_total

I just need to know where can i add where clause  where  YEAR([Date_DD])=2000   anyone can help?

Comment: Are you saying that you're using MySQL, MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL and Oracle at the same time? I, somehow, doubt it. I'd suggest you to fix tags.

Comment: IT doesnt matter for me  which sql dialect can solve this problem  any of them are accepted . i just need answer. i can convert it to others.

Comment: What would be desired result (based on sample data you posted) (BTW, it's year **20020** :))

Comment: @PBD `IT doesnt matter` on the contrary, it does matter, a lot. The specific version matters too. Different products have different dialects. MySQL only added the `OVER()` clause and windowing functions in MySQL 8, and adds *major* features even in minor releases. PostgreSQL and SQL Server are more stable and had windowing functions for quite some time, but the syntax isn't exactly the same

Comment: You're asking for the total revenue per product. That means you need a `GROUP BY product` and `SUM()`, not `OVER()`. You want revenue in 2020, so you need `WHERE Date_DD between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31'`. *After* that, you need the running total of the products in descending order, until that running total divided by the overall total reaches 0.25. That's where you can use `SUM() OVER()`

Comment: Bu group by doesnt give me anything  bcs it must work like running total when it reach  25% it must stop  or i need up to 25 percent , i think i need do while  or if else.  i date is not important main thing is to find upt to 25%

Comment: select product_name, revenue, running_total from (SELECT product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total 
FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o where running_total<=max(running_total)*0.25                              i need a code like this but need to replace running_total with something that will work

Comment: SOLVED  Could you check 
select product_name, revenue, running_total  from 

(SELECT product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total 

FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o 
where running_total<(select  max(running_total) from 

(SELECT product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total 

FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o )*0.25
group by product_name, revenue, running_total
order by running_total

Comment: just need to add year to where clause and makes problem.

Comment: select * from (
select Date_DD, product_name, revenue, running_total  from 

(SELECT Date_DD ,product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total 

FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o 
where running_total<(select  max(running_total) from 

(SELECT product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total 

FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o )*0.25  
group by Date_DD ,product_name, revenue, running_total
) f  where Date_DD between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31' order by running_total

Answer (score 0):

The question was not very descriptive; however, below might help you narrow down the issue.

Below will show up you the running total for the Product.

SELECT
product_name, revenue,
SUM(revenue) OVER (partition by product_name ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running _total
FROM
TABLE-PRODUCT_REVENUE

below would give the result if the product total is more significant than x amount

select
*,case when running _total >=1000 then 'top selling product' else null end
(
SELECT
product_name, revenue,
SUM(revenue) OVER (partition by product_name ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running _total
FROM
TABLE-PRODUCT_REVENUE
)t

where running_total >= xxx amount

Comment: i am sorry i didnt understand this code

Comment: i just need code ike this but cant use  this code                                                           
 select product_name, revenue, running_total from (SELECT product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total 
FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o where *****running_total******<=max(running_total)*0.25

Comment: Solved you could check guys
select product_name, revenue, running_total  from 

(SELECT product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total 

FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o 
where running_total<(select  max(running_total) from 

(SELECT product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total 

FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o )*0.25
group by product_name, revenue, running_total
order by running_total

Comment: select * from (
select Date_DD, product_name, revenue, running_total  from 

(SELECT Date_DD ,product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total 

FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o 
where running_total<(select  max(running_total) from 

(SELECT product_name, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER ( ORDER BY revenue DESC, product_name) AS running_total 

FROM TABLE_PRODUCT_REVENUE ) o )*0.25  
group by Date_DD ,product_name, revenue, running_total
) f  where Date_DD between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31' order by running_total